# Scala RegexParser calculator example right-associativity

Tags: scala, parsing, standard-library, parser-combinators

Javadoc for the `RegexParsers` trait contains the following example:

```
object Calculator extends RegexParsers {
     def number: Parser[Double] = """\d+(\.\d*)?""".r ^^ { _.toDouble }
     def factor: Parser[Double] = number | "(" ~> expr <~ ")"
     def term  : Parser[Double] = factor ~ rep( "*" ~ factor | "/" ~ factor) ^^ {
       case number ~ list => (number /: list) {
         case (x, "*" ~ y) => x * y
         case (x, "/" ~ y) => x / y
       }
     }
     def expr  : Parser[Double] = term ~ rep("+" ~ log(term)("Plus term") | "-" ~ log(term)("Minus term")) ^^ {
       case number ~ list => list.foldLeft(number) { // same as before, using alternate name for /:
         case (x, "+" ~ y) => x + y
         case (x, "-" ~ y) => x - y
       }
     }

     def apply(input: String): Double = parseAll(expr, input) match {
       case Success(result, _) => result
       case failure : NoSuccess => scala.sys.error(failure.msg)
     }
   }
```

When parsing expression `5 - 4 - 2` it treats it like `(5 - 4) - 2` and returns -1. How can I change this parser to be right-associative so it will actually evaluate `5 - (4 - 2)` and return 3?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to make the grammar to be right associative:

```
trait Tree
case class Node(op: String, left: Tree, right: Tree) extends Tree
case class Leaf(value: BigInt) extends Tree

class ExpressionParser extends RegexParsers {
  var result : BigInt = 0

  def number: Parser[Tree] = """-?\d+""".r ^^ { s => Leaf(BigInt(s))}

  def expr : Parser[Tree] = (term ~ ("+" | "-") ~ expr ^^ {
    case ((x ~ op) ~ y) => Node(op, x, y)
  }) | term

  def term : Parser[Tree] = (factor ~ ("*" | "/") ~ term ^^ {
    case ((x ~ op) ~ y) => Node(op, x, y)
  }) | factor

  def factor : Parser[Tree] = number | "(" ~> expr <~ ")"
```

}